# Using zc.buildout, how do I install a tarball from a website?

Tags: python, buildout, recipe

I'm trying to get zc.buildout to install Gunicorn from source. Using the following configuration:

```
[gunicorn]
recipe = collective.recipe.distutils
url = http://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/tarball/master
```

results in the following error:

```
SystemError: ('Failed', '"/usr/bin/python" setup.py -q install --install-  purelib="/mnt/hgfs/Projects/intranation/parts/site-packages" --install-platlib="/mnt/hgfs/Projects/intranation/parts/site-packages"')
```

Providing a `--install-dir` or `--prefix` doesn't help.

Is there a recipe for zc.buildout that downloads a tarball and installs it via easy_install or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "just" install it.  On the command line, "easy_install http://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/tarball/master" works fine.

The buildout equivalent would be to have a dependency on "gunicorn" (so that buildout attempts installing it) and to tell buildout that your github link is actually gunicorn. You do that with find-links:

```
[buildout]
  find-links =
      http://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/tarball/master#egg=gunicorn
  parts = console_scripts


  [console_scripts]
  recipe = zc.recipe.egg
  eggs = gunicorn
```

Comment: The buildout part of this solution is broken with the current setuptools (>= 0.7, I think, tested with 0.9.1 and buildout 2.2.0). Setuptools expects # in link to be always followed by some hash (e.g. #md5=...). I haven't found a work around so far.

Comment: Oh, you don't need to use hash anymore, so something like this would work with never setuptools + buildout -combo: http://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/tarball/master/gunicorn-1.0.tar.gz

Comment: That `.../master/gunicorn-1.0.tar.gz` link is formatted in such a way that setuptools automatically recognizes the package name and the version. The `...#egg=...` is/was needed for cases where the package name/version isn't obvious like in `.../gunicorn/tarball/master`. What's the version there? What is the package name? Setuptools cannot know.

Comment: Aggreed. The problem is that `#egg`-part is no longer allowed with the new setuptools (at least with 0.9.1). It crashes when it tries to parse checksum after `#`. Luckily, github allows anything after `.../tarball/master`and the url can be faked to include package name and version.

Comment: In `#egg=..` you also need to specify version. For example: `bin/easy_install --find-links https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.7c2/tarball/\#egg\=Django-1.7.c2 Django==1.7.c2`. Tried it witch setuptools==5.5.1.